# Why does plot_ly pie chart always turn 5th value text from white to black in R?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm making a pie chart using the plotly package in R, and whenever I have 5 choices to visualize, it always changes the 5th one to a brown/black color, despite me overriding the color to be white. In case it has something to do with the value being NA, how do I work around that? I have data that is labeled as NA, so I need to keep it named that. For what it's worth, I tried renaming to "NA ", but it still appeared the same.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
               education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "graudate", "student", "student", "nurse", "doctor"),
               fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
               aug_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
               sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
               oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
               nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5))

data2 <- data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(employee) %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(rowSums(select(cur_data_all(), contains("_20"))))) %>%
  dplyr::select(employee, sum) %>%
  distinct()



my_colors <- c("#CA001B", "#1D28B0", "#D71DA4", "#00A3AD", "#FF8200", "#753BBD", "#00B5E2", "#008578", "#EB6FBD", "#FE5000", "#6CC24A", "#D9D9D6", "#AD0C27", "#950078")

fig <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=data2$employee, values=data2$sum, 
               textinfo='label+percent', marker = list(colors = my_colors),
               insidetextorientation='horizontal')
fig

t <- list(
  family = "Arial",
  size = 18,
  color = 'white')

fig %>% layout(font=t, showlegend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set color in `insidetextfont` -

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(type='pie', labels=data2$employee, values=data2$sum, 
        textinfo='label+percent', insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        marker = list(colors = my_colors),
        insidetextorientation='horizontal')

fig
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! Quick follow up: The hover text for NA is still the brown color. I tried setting hovertext = list(color = "#FFFFFF"), but nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: In case anyone needs it, the way to fix the hover text color is to add another argument within the layout function: layout(hoverlabel = list(font = list(color = "white")))